# jQuery called multiple times

Tags: jquery, laravel

I have a simple jQuery code here, but the problem is, it fires multiple times and it takes time to load data.

```
$(document).on('click', '.pagination a', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  //   console.log($(this).attr('href'));
  var page = $(this).attr('href').split('page=')[1];
  getData(page);

});

function getData(page) {
  //    console.log("Pages "+page);
  $.ajax({
    url: "pagination?page=" + page,
  }).done(function(data) {
    $('body').html(data);
  });
}
```

this is in App.Blade.php

```
    @include('inc.navbar')
    <div style= "padding-left: 10px; padding-right:10px;">
        @include('inc.messages')
        @yield('content')
    </div >
```

This is in Index.blade.php

@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')

```
<h1>Post</h3>
  
 <div id="table_data">
@if(count($posts)>0)

    @foreach ($posts as $post)
        <div class="well" >
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                    <img style="height:300px; width:400px;" src="/storage/cover_images/{{$post->cover_image}}">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8">
                    <h3><a href="/posts/{{$post->id}}">{{$post->title}}</a></h3>
                    <small>Written on {{$post->created_at}}</small>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    @endforeach
    {{$posts->links()}}
@else
    <p>No Post Found</p>
@endif
    </div>
```

Comment: can i see the HTML code please?

Comment: Is it fires two times?

Comment: multiple times.. around (30) when I checked in browser console

Comment: Your script looks fine. You have to check If any other event bind to "a"

Comment: or can you please try with {{$posts->render()}} instead of {{$posts->links()}} ?